# View pager with fragments - showing dialog onStart

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, android-viewpager, fragment

I'm new in using view pager, I've done everything correctly, I conveted my activities into fragments and put them in FragmentPagerStateAdapter. 
When testing it in the emulator, what I noticed is that the onCtreate to the onResume are called one fragment before the actual visibility on the view pager - it makes sense, the device wants to get ready for the next step,  but the problem is that I have one fragment which calls a dialog every onStart so that actually happens on the wrong fragment.

What should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `OnPageChangeListener` on your ViewPager to detect when you navigate to the right fragment.

Comment: Thnx,  that what's I'm looking for.